# Why won't my margin(left/right) not resize when the screen is smaller?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know there is problem related to @media screen out there but sadly it didn't worked for me.
So my style.css look like this

```
    .left-align-item {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
        text-align: left; 
    }
    #logo {
        margin-top: -65px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20%; 
    } 
    ul {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 24px;
        margin-right: 20%; 
    }
```

And my responsive.css

```
@media screen and(max-width: 1360px) {
    /*GENERAL*/
    .left-align-item {
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    /*HEADER*/
    #logo {
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    ul {
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
}
```

And the head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/icon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fa/css/fontawesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fa/css/brands.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fa/css/solid.css">
</head>
```

If my screen is smaller than 1360px, the left margin is not resizing from 20% to 10%. I can't quite find the problem here.

Comment: You should create a snippet so that we can take a look at what is actually going on.

Comment: Please include the code where you are including there files?

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes it seems that the css is for specific class/tag is not overwritten by the media query when the screen is resized.

Comment: @ShreyanshKashyap I cant as stackoverflow tells that I have only code even when doing snippets

Comment: @MisterJojo No the space was missing between `and(max-width)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the documentation**:

Whitespace is required between a `not`, `and`, or `or` keyword and the following `(` character. Without this the parser parses it as a different type of token. [Details](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-syntax)

Your media query needs to have a space between `and` and the parenthesis `(`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
    /*GENERAL*/
    .left-align-item {
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    /*HEADER*/
    #logo {
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
    ul {
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine, except for the order of the tags placed in the head tag. Try posting  tag above title. Hope this might resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a specificity issue. Check the order of style links, make sure *responsive.css* is declared after *style.css*

Also check your media query syntax: it must have a space between *and*

Comment: This can be. However, the OP has not stated if they are using different stylesheet files for this.

Comment: It is declared as you mentioned